# Transfer/copy EC2 instance, on which Nodejs+MongoDB app through Bitnami is deployed, to another aws account

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-ec2, mean-stack, bitnami

I previously deployed my Nodejs+MongoDB application on AWS EC2 instance, now I want to transfer it to another AWS account. I followed this video-

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/account-transfer-ec2-instance/

I was able to run the new instance(after transfer) but apps folder is missing there which contains the nodejs app code.

Source EC2 instance folder structure:
**apps  htdocs  stack**

Destination EC2 instance folder structure:
**bitnami_credentials  htdocs  stack**

Note: While copying the instance, got the error that Bitnami version(used on source account) is not available now, so used a new version on destination AWS account.

Comment: Is all your data on the root volume?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bitnami Engineer here. If you want to migrate the existing installation to a new instance or new account, you can simply spin up a new instance using the latest Bitnami MEAN stack in the new account and copy the whole installation directory from one instance to the other one.

- You can create the backup by running these commands in the current instance

```
cd
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh stop
sudo tar -pczvf mean-backup.tar.gz /opt/bitnami
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh start
```

- You will need to transfer that `mean-backup.tar.gz` file to the new instance
- And recover the backup there

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh stop
sudo mv /opt/bitnami /tmp/bitnami-backup
sudo tar -pxzvf mean-backup.tar.gz -C /
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh start
```

You can find more information about this in our documentation

https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/infrastructure/mean/administration/backup-restore/